# How to make invisible check box in repeater control while exporting to excel vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

I am very new to vb.net. I am exporting data from Repeater control to Excel; I am doing it fine but in my repeater control I have a check box. I just don't want to display it in my Excel. How can I exclude it?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="fillmrepeater" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Select
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")%>'
                            name="cP" id="cP">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem("Name"), "Name")%>)%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

and in codebehind while exporting to Excel

```
    Private Sub exportExcel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.exportExcelClickEventArgs) Handles exportExcel_Click.Click
     For Each repter As RepeaterItem In fillmrepeater.Items
                    If repter.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or repter.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
                        Dim ckb As New CheckBox()
                        CType(repter.FindControl("chkPerson"), CheckBox).Visible = False
    
                    End If
                Next


      Response.Clear()
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=report.xls;")
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        Dim sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim hw As New Html32TextWriter(sw)

        fillmrepeater.RenderControl(hw)
        Response.Write("<table>")
        Response.Write(sw.ToString())
        Response.Write("</table>")
        Response.Flush()            
        Response.End()
      END Sub
   END Class
```

I am getting object reference not set to instance of an object
so I am getting null here. I just need to making visible=false to checkck box.

Comment: I don't see any "export to excel" code. How are you doing that?

Comment: @pradeep Kumar  sory   for that i had added it u can see now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put the `RunAt="server"` attribute on your checkbox so that it is available in the code-behind.

   ```html
   <input type="checkbox" runat="server" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")%>' name="chkPerson" id="chkPerson" />
   ```
2. Modify your code as follows:

   ```
   For Each repter As RepeaterItem In fillmrepeater.Items
       If repter.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or repter.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
           CType(repter.FindControl("chkPerson"), HtmlInputCheckBox).Visible = False
       End If
   Next
   ```

**EDIT :**

To hide the Header Row:

1. Mark your HeaderTemplate `<TR>` with `runat="server"` so that we can access it in the code-behind.

   ```html
       <HeaderTemplate>
               <tr runat="server" id="HeaderRow">
                   <td>
                       Select
                   </td>
                   <td>
                       Name
                   </td>
               </tr>
       </HeaderTemplate>
   ```
2. [you already know what to do now :) ]

   ```
   Dim headerRow As HtmlTableRow = fillmrepeater.Controls(0).FindControl("HeaderRow")
   headerRow.Visible = False
   ```

Comment: yes it's working fine i have one more small problem i need to hide header too "Select" how do i exclude it in excel it's printing Select header

Comment: I updated the post to show how to hide the header row.